# Finding how many solutions an equation $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right) = 1$ has in the interval $x\in(0.001, 0.002)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

Given equation $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right) = 1$, find how many roots it has in interval $x\in(0.001, 0.002)$.

Because I've never done this kind of problems in my life, I'm in blind spot. How can I find the number?

Comment: Hint: Which angles $\alpha$ are such that $\sin(\alpha)=1$ ? If $\pi/x$ is one of those, write the equation  $\pi/x=\alpha$ and "make x the subject"...

Comment: Well, solution is $x = \frac{2}{4n + 1}$. What do you mean by "making x the subject"? :-)

Comment: It's what you have done ($x$= something : $x$ is the subject of the sentence "x is equal to ...") : Now that you know $x = \frac{2}{4n + 1}$, the larger $n$, the smaller $x$, till it fits in the given interval...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I assume you mean "solutions", and not "roots".*

$\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{x}\right)=1$ can be solved to give

$$x=\frac{2}{4n+1}, \quad n\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

Let your range be $[x_1,x_2]$. We want to count the number of $x$s that satisfy 
$$x_1<x(n)=\frac{2}{4n+1}<x_2.$$

Let's plug in some numbers! I find that the first $n$ that makes $x(n)<x_2$ is $n=250.$ Similarly, I find that the last $n$ before $x(n)\leq x_1$ is $n=499$. So there are $499-250+1=250$ solutions!

Comment: I get that stage, but I'm having trouble in finding, *how many* solutions are there in the interval $x\in(0.001, 0.002)$.

Comment: @AcceleratetotheInfinity Cool, I'm updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: @AcceleratetotheInfinity Done. Please let me know if anything is still unclear.